# Marble probability of randomly picking a blue marble 3rd?

Tags: probability

A bag contains 10 identically-shaped marbles: 3 red, 4 blue, and 3 green. A person randomly pulls out the marbles one by one (without replacement).

I'm not understanding why the probability of picking a blue marble 3rd is 4/10 - I'm trying to calculate the probability, and just not getting 4/10 though I understand that's the correct answer. Can someone please assist? Thank you!

[Wolfram Alpha Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqMNX.png)

In the calculation above, I'm trying:

1. if all three are blue;
2. if the first is not blue but the next 2 are blue;
3. if the first two are not blue but the 3rd is blue;
4. if the first is blue, second is not blue, and third is blue

As a note, I aggregated the red + green marbles as I didn't think their colors mattered specifically, just that 6 marbles are not blue

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I don't understand your calculation.  If you want to sum over all the paths,  you need more than four paths.  If the third one is blue there are nine possibilities for the first two.

Comment: Hi! I am calculating 1) if all three are blue; 2) if the first is not blue but the next 2 are blue; 3) if the first two are not blue but the 3rd is blue; 4) if the first is blue, second is not blue, and third is blue (I aggregated the red + green marbles as I didn't think they mattered specifically, just that 6 marbles are not blue)

Comment: Your case $4$, $BNB$ where $N$ means "Not Blue" should have numerator $(4\times 6\times 3)$.  It should coincide with your case $2$ in value.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your method, just an arithmetic error.  To be sure, it's better to do the problem by different means.  You wouldn't want to do it this way if you had hundreds of balls of each color and you were asking about the $90^{th}$ draw or whatever.  Of course, the point is that any ball is equally likely to be drawn in any position.

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand the downvote (and have upvoted to offset).  The OP clearly states the problem, has proposed a sensible methodology, has included a computation which is correct save for a careless error, and has indicated that they are aware of the correct answer but can't spot the error in this one.  I don't see a problem with the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The methodology is solid, but there is a simple arithmetic error.  Specifically, the cases $\#2$ and $\#4$ should give the same value.  Both should be $\frac {6\times 4\times 3}{10\times 9\times 8}$ with some permutation of the factors in the numerator.

Of course, it's better to simply remark that each ball has an equal chance of being chosen in each position, thus each ball has a $\frac 1{10}$ of being chosen fourth, and we just multiply by $4$ because there are four blue balls.  Of course, this applies equally well to each position, there is nothing special about the fourth position.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thank you so much for all your help here!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Colours have no preference for position, so the a priori probability of there being a blue marble at *any* position with random placement will be equal to the fraction of blue to
the total number